# GIT - changing code in an earlier commit so that it's reflected in the commits after

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

So I'm currently making a site with HTML5 and and I'm quite a ways in when I realize that I forgot to put in the HTML5 resets in to my css file.

Currently I'm about 10 commits in and what I would like to do is to add the reset code in to the css file into my very first commit and have it present in the rest of the commits after.

I read around a bit and I think git rebase is the way to go but Im not really sure how to use it correctly.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git) seems to be close to what I want to do, but Im not well versed in Git yet to adapt this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Check out the past commit you want to change with `git checkout`.

2) Tag this past commit using `git tag PastCommit`.

3) Use `git checkout -b FixBranch` to create a new branch called FixBranch.

4) Add the new file in and make a new commit on FixBranch.

5) Switch to your master branch using `git checkout master`.

6) Tag using `git tag BACKUP` in case you screw something up - just to be safe before a rebase :)

7) Use `git rebase --onto FixBranch PastCommit` - this will rebase the stuff between PastCommit and the head of master onto FixBranch.

8) Tidy up using `git tag -d PastCommit`, `git tag -d BACKUP` and `git branch -d FixBranch`.

9) Use `git gc` to garbage collect and get rid of any dangling commits.

Note that you can (and should!) visualise all this in `gitk` so that you can see what you're doing (and make sure I haven't missed anything - this is a bit off the top of my head).

Addendum: I just tried this on a test repository and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stuart, but I get a bunch of merge errors at every few commits. It also adds a new blank line after each line in the css file.

Just to clarify, what I'm doing is not adding a new file but editing my existing css file and adding the code in to it.

Comment: @Jay: You'll probably get merge errors at every commit in your history where you changed the .css file - that's normal with a rebase. You have to manually merge the changes in, which is a bit of a pain, but it's the only way I know (it makes sense that you'd need to as well if you think about what you're actually trying to achieve here). A good merge tool like WinDiff will help - you can set Git up to use it. Not sure why you're getting blank lines, unless it's a cross-platform line ending issue.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I see, I guess I was expecting it be a clean merge hehe.. And I'm sure its a line-ending issue coz I noticed that my document is in CRLF and I'm currently on a Mac. Its probably too late to change that now.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout `git rebase -i` where -i stands for "interactive". There you can "squash" commits together.

Comment: Thanks, but can I retain my commit history as is?

Comment: No, because you are changing your commits.

Comment: @JayDropout: What do you mean by retaining your history? A commit represents a snapshot of the tree, so by definition, subsequent commits will be changed - their contents are different. But you can still retain commits corresponding to the original ones, plus the change you snuck in. So yes, you're rewriting history, but no, the commits won't disappear, they'll just be changed.