# Git rebase interactive drop vs deleting the commit line

Tags: git, git-rebase

What is the difference from `drop` in the Git interactive rebase and just deleting the line of the commit?

Answer (score 79):

There is no difference by default; it's just another way to say the same thing.

*But,* if you set [`rebase.missingCommitsCheck`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_configuration) to `warn` or `error`, then removing a line will trigger a warning (useful for detecting a messed-up cut-and-paste).

Then setting the line to `drop` explicitly tells Git that you want to drop that commit, and no warning is shown for it.

Answer (score 51):

There *is* in fact another small difference:

You can explicitly "drop" all commits. The effect will be the same as a reset.

However if you just delete all lines, then git will tell you "Nothing to do".

Usually you would not use rebase anyway in that case. I learned the difference only when I tried to explain removing a commit with rebase to a co-worker using a dummy commit.

Answer (score 13):

Marking a commit as `drop` is the same as deleting the line.

The commit will be dropped/ignored.

See when you scroll down:

> If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.

The drop command was added in [2.6.0-rc1](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/277530):

> "git rebase -i" learned "drop commit-object-name subject" command
>      as another way to skip replaying of a commit.