# How to delete a only a specific commit in the middle of the git log

Tags: git

I want only to delete a specific commit in the middle of a git log. It shouldn't be affected to above commits.

Comment: from local copy or remote?

Answer (score 65):

> It shouldn't be affected to above commits.

If you remove a commit from the middle of a branch, or really anywhere except possibly the HEAD of a branch, you will *rewrite* the history of that branch.  This is because the tools you would use to effect this, namely `git rebase --interactive` and `git filter-branch`, would need to recommit everything which comes after the commit you removed.  This is usually not desirable for a public shared branch because it forces everyone to take pretty draconian measures to keep up with that change.

Rather, a safer bet for you would be to use `git revert`:

```
git revert <SHA-1 of commit to delete>
```

This will add a *new* commit on the top of your branch which effectively undoes everything which the middle commit did.

By the way, if you *really* want to remove that commit, I would recommend doing an interactive rebase.

Answer (score 59):

If the commit were not pushed to a remote server, you can use `git rebase` to modify the git history.

You can do that:

```
git rebase -i commit-hash^
```

It will show a list of commits. The first line should be the commit you want to delete. Remove that line from the file you edited, save and close.

If you did push to a remote server prior to do that, note that the commits after the commit you just deleted were rewritten based on the commit before the one you just deleted from the history. For that particular reason, all of the commits are changed because your history just diverged. So if you try to push that, it won't be fast-forward and you'll have to force the push.

For that reason, if you're not familiar with `git rebase` I suggest keeping a branch pointing to the branch you were modifying the history in case something goes wrong.

Also, if that particular commit is shared accross multiple branches, diverging the history of one branch will cause multiple problems as you won't be able to easily merge one branch from the old history to the branch in the new history. It will duplicate many commit and the commit you deleted in one branch won't be deleted in the others.

Think of it has modifying git history is like time travel. Any change at one point create a new parallel universe. Everything that was after the change in the past really is impacted by the change you did in the past.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `git cherry-pick` for this. Let's say your git log looks like this. and you want to remove the 2nd commit from your branch.

```
COMMITS    MESSAGES
abcd123    4th commit message
xyze456    3rd commit message
98y65r4    2nd commit message wants to be removed.
bl8976t    1st commit message
```

STEP 1 - Checkout the last correct commit: `git checkout bl8976t`

STEP 2 - Create a new branch from there: `git checkout -b commit-remove`

STEP 3 - Cherry pick commits you want to keep: `git cherry-pick xyze456` and `git cherry-pick abcd123`

STEP 4 - Checkout your original branch: `git checkout master`

STEP 5 - Reset original branch to last usable commit: `git reset --hard bl8976t`

STEP 6 - Merge the new branch onto the original branch: `git merge commit-remove`

STEP 7 - Check that the original branch has the correct commits: `git log`

STEP 8 - Push the original branch to the remote repo: `git push --force origin original-branch-name`

You are done.

Beware that this could have adverse effects on other users who are working on the same repository/branch.

Comment: in my case or now (git latest version) on step 8 i use command `git push --force origin latest sha commit from merge:original-branch-name`

Comment: This is a better approach when compared to rebase and revert.

Comment: @PawaraSiriwardhane, Why is this better? It takes many more steps and if you the more commits that exist after the one to be removed the more lines of code are needed.

Comment: i guess easiest is to clone branch, and cherry pick wanted commits from original branch to it

Comment: This should be the accurate thing. Thank you !

Answer (score 7):

I agree with all of the above solutions, especially if you're in a tight spot. If the middle commit has no important changes to its child commits you can also do a interactive rebase and drop the changes you don't want.

I usually use this when I accidentally pick up commits from other devs I didn't need.

Example Scenario, I have the following 3 commits:

```
865962a1f5 Update Book Title
a3b091b427 Remove Book Link From Header
838e768df2 Add New Book To Book List
```

I no longer wish to remove my book link from the header for some reason.

**Step 1.**
`git rebase -i Head~3`

This will output:

```
pick 865962a1f5 Update Book Title
pick a3b091b427 Remove Book Link From Header
pick 838e768df2 Add New Book To Book List
```

**step 2. replace 'pick' with 'drop' for the middle commit**

```
pick 865962a1f5 Update Book Title
drop a3b091b427 Remove Book Link From Header
pick 838e768df2 Add New Book To Book List
```

**step 3. Write and Quit**

You may need to do some conflict resolution after, but if the change is simple enough, this will drop the middle commit and leave you with the following history:

```
865962a1f5 Update Book Title
838e768df2 Add New Book To Book List
```

You can now either force push this onto the remote branch `git push -f`, beware this is somewhat destructive or you can create a new branch and switch your MR to the new one!

Comment: This is actually useful when you're the only dev working on a project and yes, destructive.

Answer (score 5):

if you're using intelliJ

Say your branch X is something like this

commit [A] <-- last commit

commit [B]

commit [C]

commit [D]

And you want to delete the 2 commits B and C.

1- Right click commit D using the git log dialog (last commit before the one you want to delete) and create a new branch from it call it Y, intellij will automatically checkout at branch Y

[New branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOxgL.png)

3- You can see your branches  in the left column of the git log dialog, right click on branch X and select Compare with current

[Compare with current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSzSp.png)

Now you'll see this dialog

[Compare dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujay3.png)

4- You can right click commit A and choose Cherry-pick

[Cherry pick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OoyQ.png)

Now in branch Y you have commit A and D, resolve the conflicts, commit and push.