# Remove a past git commit from history - non-interactively

Tags: git, automation, git-rebase

Reading the answers to:

[Git - Remove commit from history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30893040/1593077)

I only see suggestions involving interactively editing a TODO file. Is there a way to drop a single commit, given its hash, and keep ("pick") all subsequent commits, without user interaction?

Comment: It looks like it can be done using the `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` environment variable and for example `sed`: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '/p <SHA1>/d'" git rebase -i <UPSTREAM>` (the `-i` switch is required: it will edit the `/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` file in-place). The `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` hint found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner

Comment: I also was wondering of this question earilier, but I think that `git-rebase` is "too porcelain" for this case, and it probably can be resolved by using some plumbing commands.

Comment: @fluffy: Don't you mean `/pick <SHA1>/d`?

Comment: When you say "remove the commit", do you want to keep what's in the commit, or do you want to discard that too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318688/7976758 : `git rebase --onto SHA^ SHA` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+remove+commit

Comment: @einpoklum Yes. My git is configured to use abbreviations, like p for pick, d for drop, etc.

Comment: @AlectoIrenePerez: "drop" is a keyword you can use when editing the rebase todo.

Comment: @matt: 1. Because I already know what I want to do, and I don't want to type as much. 2. For use in automation scripts.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic solution:**

A solution due to a comment by @phd, and originally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318688/7976758):

To remove the commit with hash value `SHA`, write:

```
git rebase --onto SHA^ SHA
```

But remember that rebasing and merges have complex interactions, which you should [read about](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges) if your history involves merges.

**Cherry on top:**

You can create an alias for this idiom, via `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    drop = !git rebase --onto $1^ $1 && :
```

with which you will be able to write simply:

```
git drop SHA
```