# Git: Needed a single revision error

Tags: git

I initialized a new git in my project and I have only two commits so far. My log is like below

```
git log
commit e515e5b8dcbd8f1ea4a7a7d4a1efb82a1a0aee7a
Author: Olkun Mustafa <olkun.mustafa@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 3 10:04:20 2014 +0300

    Temp commit

commit 71781bf0a7807351a56d5155dac94169ea700527
Author: Olkun Mustafa <olkun.mustafa@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 3 10:01:42 2014 +0300

    First Commit
```

When I try to rebase this commits I get error like below

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~2
```

I quite research at google but I haven't found solution till now.

Comment: What result after you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Are you trying to undo your commits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change first commit of project with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git)

Answer (score 259, accepted):

In your case, there is no `HEAD~2`, since you only have 2 commits, hence the "`Needed a single revision`" error message.
Try:

```
 git rebase -i --root
```

see more about `--root` at "[Change first commit of project with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309391/6309)"

Comment: I was getting only the "fatal: invalid upstream head~2" even though I had four commits in the log. The "single revision" message wasn't showing for me. However, this fixed me right up! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This doesn't apply to your case, but may help others. If on Linux, make sure `HEAD` is capitalized. If you use lowercase `head` like the first example below (because you are used to working on Windows or Mac and those allow lowercase `head`), you will get the `fatal: Needed a single revision` error!

Or you can use `@` as an alias for `HEAD`, then you won't need to worry to forgetting to capitalize it.

```
# wrong on linux
git rebase --interactive head~2

# correct on linux
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2

# correct on all
git rebase --interactive @~2
```

Comment: thank you so much! I struggled with this for a few hours and capitalized `HEAD` is the fix!

Comment: ⁺¹ for the advice on `@`.