# Unable to rebase including the first commit in Git?

Tags: git

Yesterday I saw a repository which had been rebased, resulting in a duplicated first commit, i.e. the original first commit was split into two commits, but the commit message was the same for both.

To squash these two commits, I tried to run `git rebase -i --root` several times, but the first commit was not listed in the rebase list (inside the editor). The problem could be solved easily by using `git reflog`, but nevertheless I have no explanation for the mentioned state of the repository.

What actions can lead to situations in which the first commit is not included in the rebase list after running `git rebase -i --root`? What is the best way to get out of such situations?

Comment: Are you using Git version `1.7.12` or later?

Comment: I cannot check that right now, but it could be an older version.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git

Comment: OK, I am going to check the version.

Comment: Things apart, if you have a version <2.0, I highly advise you to update... 1.7.12 is what, 6 years old?