# Git rearrange root commit and second commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

I'm learning how to use GIT and Bitbucket. Bitbucket Admin (not me) created a remote repository.

In this repository, I have committed my changes 'A' to Master branch ( this is now root/parent/first commit in repository ).

Now, I have committed another change 'B' to Master branch.
How can I rearrange the commits in remote and local repository and erase all  previous history of initial commit ?

In Bitbucket, it should look like below:

Before : In Master branch

B "New Commit"

A "Initial Commit"

---

After: In Master branch

A "Initial Commit"

B "New Commit"

Commit 'B' was supposed to be the first/initial commit but I accidentally pushed my changes in wrong direction.

Is it possible to correct this using git commands ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rebase+root+commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change first commit of project with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git)

Answer (score 0):

The best general answer here is probably that you should do a `git revert` to functionally undo the first commit `A`:

```
git revert <SHA-1 of A commit>
```

To find out the commit hash for `A`, just type `git log` and search for the hash of the very first commit.  It will look something like `3kd983ngl74ok`.

This will add a *new* commit to your `master` branch which functionally undoes whatever the `A` commit added.  So, your `master` branch will now look like:

```
master: A -- B -- R
```

where `R` is the new revert commit.  But, the `master` branch will behave as if `A` never happened.

This is the safest option assuming you have already published your branch on the repository.

Another possibility here would be to do an interactive rebase and surgically remove the `A` commit from the history.  But, this would be more work, more complex, and would also open the possibility of bad things happening when you force push `master` to the remote.

Comment: how to surgically remove the 'A' commit ? I have tried the revert method and ended up like what you have mentioned ( A - B - R ).

Comment: That's a long answer and you shouldn't be doing it to a published branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue using orphan branch. I have used following commands:

From your local repository (master branch), create a orphan branch

**git checkout --orphan orphan_name**

Remove all files

**git rm -rf .**

Add new changes

**git add .**

Commit the change

**git commit -a -m "Initial Commit"**

Push the change

**git push origin orphan_name**

Checkout the master branch again

**git checkout master**

Overwrite "master" with "orphan_name":

**git reset --hard orphan_name**

Force the push to your remote repository:

**git push -f origin master**

Delete the orphan branch

**git push --delete origin orphan_name**

I know it is a risk in doing this in published branch / public repo. But it was helpful to rearrange the root commit with orphan branch commit.

Comment: Why did you push the orphan branch at all?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried without pushing orphan branch to remote repository, but it was showing error.