# removing commit history in git

Tags: git, heroku, commit

I was playing around with `heroku` and `django` .To host my django app on `heroku` ,I had to change many files(`settings,urls,requirements.txt` etc) so many times back and forth (so as to get things right) .As a result there are so many commits in the repo.Problem is that I have the stable version of the code(before the heroku specific modifications were done) on `github` and now it would look ugly if I push to my `github` all those commits which I did to get app working on `heroku` .

So,I want to remove all those commits,and get back to the older stable version.Then I can add the `heroku` specific modifications and just do one commit.The way I  see it ,I can do

1.pull from `github` and then add `heroku` specific changes.Then commit,push to `github`,push to `heroku`.

2.In `gitk` ,I can select the last pre-heroku commit, right click and do 'Reset master branch to here'.Then make `heroku` related changes,commit ,push to `github`,push to `heroku`.

Which is the correct way to do this?Suppose the pre-heroku commit was ver6, and my current commit is ver10,there are 4 unnecessary commits which I made.I need to wipe them clean ,and make the next commit ver7.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do a git pull to get the latest version offline.
2. [git rebase --interactive](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits) your branch with modifications. Select squash for everything except the first one to make just one commit. (change the commit message to something sensible)
3. git cherry-pick that one commit on whatever development branch you will merge with your stable branch.
4. merge and push

Answer (score 2):

Method is pretty similar to that in Github which had been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/4720652). Though I will rewrite the answer for Heroku.

In order to delete commit history

- Create a new branch and checkout to it `git checkout --orphan branch_new`
- Add all files `git add -A`
- Commit `git commit -m "Deleting commit history"`
- Delete master branch `git branch -D master`
- Rename the branch to master `git branch -m master`
- Force push the update to repository `git push -f heroku master`