# Git metadata - is there a way to add git metadata that is independent of each branch?

Tags: git, git-clone

**End goal:** I want to have files that are tracked by Git, but have those files be the *same version for all branches*. If you gitignore files, those are the same for all branches, but unfortunately aren't tracked. When I run `git push` or the like, I need these files to passed between repos, etc.

For example, the data that is in .git folder is typically git-ignored. I want to add some data to my repo so that the data is independent of all branches, but still appears in all branches, and when you clone the repo, the data shows up.

Is this possible? So for example, if the `.git` dir looks like:

```
.git/
  branches/
  hooks/
  objects/
  config
  HEAD
  index
```

I was thinking of adding a folder:

```
.git/
  .oresoftware/
```

and putting my data in there, where that data is independent of all branches.

I don't think this will work, because the data in the .git repo isn't really tracked. I am looking for something that's tracked by git, but is the same for all branches...

**Update**: After reading the answers and thinking about this for awhile, I thought maybe if I amend the initial commit with new files, then it could magically work, but of course that's not how Git works, each commit is a total snapshot, so changing historical commits after the fact won't change newer ones.

Comment: Put some code as the initial commit?

Comment: @evolutionxbox huh? sorry I didn't catch that

Comment: To have tracked code available in all branches, it must be in a a parent commit of all branches. Like an initial commit.

Comment: Right, good idea, but if the data is added later, much after an initial commit. I have to handle the case that the data was not in an initial commit. For many reasons, but including the reason that the data needs to be altered later on.

Comment: If you want your data to be available in all branches then why do you want to add in the `.git\` folder when you know it won't be tracked?

Comment: Ok. Either the content needs to be added to every branch, or be inside an ancestor commit of every branch.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think I understood your query now. Basically, you need to add the data in a visible folder so that git tracks it i.e. `git add <data>` in one of the branches and `merge` this branch to `master` and then consequently synchronize other two branches with the `master` (`git fetch origin master && git merge origin master`). In this particular case, since you added a new file/folder in git, you won't face merge conflicts. Finally, your data will be available in all the branches.
**EDIT** (based on another user's comment): `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>` is another way where you can apply a specific commit to a branch.

Comment: Why bother merging? You could cherry pick the commit, that way only the new content gets added.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yep updated the answer. I chose a rather simple way as I think the asker is not well-versed with git. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> ... data that is in .git folder is typically git-ignored.

This is not just *typical*, it's *necessary* for Git's security model.

(In the past, Git had some bugs in which you could create files named `.GIT/whatever` and they would go into the repository, then exist in `.git/whatever` on checkouts on Windows and MacOS, since those systems default to ignoring case: a file named `.GIT/foo` is actually created as `.git/foo` since `.git` exists at that point.  This bug has been corrected in modern Git.)

> I want to add some data to my repo so that the data is independent of all branches, but still appears in all branches, and when you clone the repo, the data shows up.
>
> Is this possible?

No—but there are other ways to get what you want.

Cloning a repository is equivalent to the following steps:

- Create an empty directory (or use an existing one): `mkdir path`.
- Create a new, empty Git repository there: `cd path && git init`.
- Add a *remote*, usually named `origin`, for the URL: `git remote add origin url`.
- Fetch everything from that remote: `git fetch origin`.
- Create a branch via `git checkout`: `git checkout branch`, where *branch* is normally created from a remote-tracking name that was created during the preceding `git fetch` step.

There are a number of historical peculiarities, plus issues if something goes wrong, so the above is not quite perfect.  It also omits an optional `git config` step.  The branch chosen at the end, to be created, is the one from your `-b` argument.  If your `-b` argument names a tag instead of a branch, Git just checks out a detached HEAD without creating any branch.  If you don't give a `-b` argument, Git uses directives from the remote to figure out which branch to create.  The default, and thus the usual result, is `master`, created to point to the same commit as `origin/master`.

Once there is a branch, or some branches, in a repository, those branches—more precisely, those *names*, like `master` and `develop` and so on—are owned by whoever owns the repository.  They can do whatever they want with them; you, as the owner of the repository that they cloned, can do nothing to stop them.  You cannot *make* them have a file show up in their branches.  Of course we can say that about the entire repository, so that's a bit silly as an argument: it's true that you cannot control them; the whole *repository* is theirs to do with as they will.

Presumably, then, what you want is to make it *easy* for them to install some content into a file somewhere.  The way to do that is to have the content accessible by some simple name.  But what names does Git offer?

Well, at the bottom level, what Git stores are *commits*, which in turn store *trees* (path names) that store *blobs* (file content).  The actual name of any given commit, tree, or blob is a raw hash ID, and hash IDs are unpredictable and not generally useful to, or accessible by, humans.  So you *could* tell people, say, to:

> extract hash ID `1bdc91e282c5393c527b3902a208227c19971b84` into `.oresoftware/foo`

but (1) the hash ID is incomprehensible, and (2) who wants to type all that in?  And if you have multiple files, you'll need one blob hash ID per file.  Yuck!

There is a better way to do this though.  You can create a *commit* object that contains files named `.oresoftware/foo`, `.oresoftware/bar`, and so on.  This is an ordinary commit that can be extracted into an ordinary work-tree at any time.

Now suppose that you put this commit on a branch named `ORESOFTWARE`.  You can then tell people that they should:

> run `git checkout origin/ORESOFTWARE -- .oresoftware && git reset .oresoftware`

which, admittedly, is not really any shorter, but at least is not full of incomprehensible hash IDs.

The `git checkout` will create `.oresoftware` in their work-tree, as long as they have the remote-tracking name, which `git fetch` (from `git clone`) will have created.<sup>1</sup>  The `git reset .oresoftware` will remove the `.oresoftware` entries that `git checkout` created in their index.  If `/.oresoftware/` is listed in `.gitignore`, the work-tree files will be ignored.  This means you have to have a `.gitignore` in each tip commit of each branch, so that the directory will be conveniently automatically ignored, but that is easy to do.

Last, instead of directing people to run two apparently-magic Git commands, you can say:

> run `./setup.sh`

which means you can put the two Git commands into a shell script, `setup.sh`, that you provide in every branch-tip just like you provide the `.gitignore` file in every branch tip.  Moreover, you can even have your software-build process  *automatically* run `./setup.sh`, and then you don't need any special action on their part.

Should you decide to change the files that go in `.oresoftware`, you just need to make a new commit on your own `ORESOFTWARE` branch.  This can (and probably should) contain just the `.oresoftware` directory.  Because the build process re-extracts the directory with each build, a `git fetch` will get your users an updated `origin/ORESOFTWARE` remote-tracking name, which will then get them updated files.

Comment: This might work, but honestly is not that convenient for my use case. The overhead of maintaining an extra branch over the long run is annoying at best. I am not saying it's your fault, I guess it's a limitation of Git's model.

Comment: I wish there were a way to git-ignore something, but still keep it in version control. It would be like branch-ignoring something, but not repo-ignoring it. So when you merge local branches with remote branches, that's when it would come time to do a merge.

Comment: or instead of git-notes, what about git-stash? effectively, I think git-stash is similar to your solution though

Comment: `git notes` makes commits. They're special in that the names of the files *in* the commits are themselves hash IDs, so that when `git log` is looking at a commit and has the hash ID in hand, Git can look in the commit to which `refs/notes/commits` points. Suppose the commit in question is `a1b2c3...`. If that notes commit contains a file named `a1b2c3...`, `git log` displays the *content* of that notes file.

Comment: Meanwhile, `git stash` makes ... commits. You might sense a theme developing here. :-)

Comment: yeah i see the theme :) hmmm this is not easy, honestly gitignoring the file seems like the best way to go