# Initialising a repo using an existing commit as the initial commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitkraken

I'm very much a newbie in this space, competent with GitKraken client GUI, and comfortable with the terminal/command line (with some guidance) - all help is appreciated.

**Clients**
Remote = Bitbucket
Local = GitKraken

**Objective**
Taking a commit from an old GitKraken repo and putting it in a new repo by itself to start fresh.

I've tried making a new repo, adding the old one as a remote, cherry-picking the commit and then detaching the remote, but all the commits from the remote remain, defeating the point.

I've also tried modifying the hidden .git folder to see if I can splice the commit I need, but everything is so entangled my efforts have been futile.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you consider just cloning the old repo somewhere in a folder, delete the `.git` and then `git init` fresh? Your initial commit will have a tree identical (albeit in a different repo) to the old repo's current commit.

Comment: `git checkout --orphan`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980631/what-is-git-checkout-orphan-used-for