# Remove old aliases and email from ALL commits

Tags: git, github, directory, delete-file

I have just noticed that my computer name and personal email were used as alias and email instead of my GitHub username and email.

Is there a way to completely remove ALL commits as well as all the history from GitHub?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is! See below.

**However,** in this case you might also be interested to **just replace your name and email address** on all the commits: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

---

From [how to delete all commit history in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716658/how-to-delete-all-commit-history-in-github) and [Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683279/make-the-current-commit-the-only-initial-commit-in-a-git-repository)

It depends on if you want to remove all configuration as well. If that's not an issue:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <github-uri>
git push -u --force origin master
```

You can save your `.git/config` before, then restore it after.

---

Alternatively, leave the code in its current state but remove everything before (by making a new branch the new 'master' branch)

```
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
git add -A
git commit -am "commit message"
git branch -D master
git branch -m master
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: I changed my email in a sourceforge git repo some time ago. For instructions for how downstream users should catch up look at the 2014-03-07 [news entry](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/news.html).