# How to delete all commits about a certain file type?

Tags: git

This is a follow-up of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525675/how-to-resize-the-remote-repository-without-deleting-all-the-commit-history)

Brief background: The size of the remote repository is far larger than the local version which was caused by pushing a lot of .pngs that were later on deleted by `rm filename`; this happened on a machine I don't have access to.

My attempts to reduce the size [failed,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525675/how-to-resize-the-remote-repository-without-deleting-all-the-commit-history)  but I was made aware of [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository). I then tried to get rid of all commits that are about images i.e. .png files. I used the following command:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *.png' HEAD
```

However, I then get the message:

> Rewrite 9625aa4ef9368d45b69c605172595322d3da1ea4 (507/507)
>
> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged

and the size of the remote repository is still the same.

How would I use it correctly? There is only one branch, the master branch, in the repository.

Comment: Did the wrong commit happen on the `master` branch? If not, then run `git filter-branch` on the correct branch.

Comment: Also, are all the `*.png` files in the top level directory? The `--tree-filter` is run from the top level of a temporary directory containing a complete `git checkout` of each commit, one commit at a time. This is very slow, so usually it's better to use the `--index-filter` for simple cases like this: the index filter avoids the whole extract/modify/rebuild-index sequence. (However, a tree filter lets you use the full power of the OS on the resulting tree.)

Comment: @Leon: Yes, the commits happened on the master branch.

Comment: @torek: the `--tree-filter` part runs through relatively fast, time is not an issue here. Problem is that it does not find any commits i.e. does not change anything which I do not fully understand as there are several pngs in the repository.

Comment: To expand a bit on the previous comment: let's say `foo.png` is in commit `master~5` and removed in `master~4`. But, it's actually named `dir1/dir2/foo.png`. Your tree filter will not remove it because `*.png` does not look inside `dir1`, much less `dir2`. You would need a tree filter with `rm -f dir1/dir2/*.png` or `find . -name '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 rm`, for instance.

Comment: @torek: Ok, I did not know that. I will give that a try as well; as it is only about one directory, it should be fast to test it.