# How to reset Bitbucket repo to beginning without deleting the repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to reset my remote and local BitBucket git repository to the very beginning, removing all commits, files, history, etc.

How can I do this without deleting the repository itself?

Answer (score 2):

if you have a clone of the repository you can use terminal to enter the directory for the repository and do

```
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
git rm *
git rm -r *
git commit -am "resetting"
git branch -D master
git branch -m master
git push -f origin master
```

commit -am appends to the most recent commit
branch -D deletes the master branch and its commit history
branch -m renames the new branch as master

This will delete the files locally as well

answer based on [this previous answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716658/how-to-delete-all-commit-history-in-github)

Comment: $ git branch -m master
error: refname refs/heads/latest_branch not found
fatal: Branch rename failed

Answer (score 0):

For all branches/tags on the repo, you could just:

`git push origin :some-branch-or-tag`

Adjust the name of the remote and the branch or tag you want to remove from the repo.

Comment: [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)

Comment: Does the remote have a working tree? If that's the case then you are trying to remote the branch that is checked out on the remote. That would explain it.

Comment: I have a master branch and 1 tag. I have cloned the repository to my local machine and made 6 commits, the files match on the local and remote repositories. I now just want to remove everything completely on local and remote and start again.

Comment: You could create the first commit on your local master and push --force it on the remote master. That would provide basically the same result (without having to resort to _deleting_ master from the remote, if it's not allowing you to).