# Reduce '.git' folder size

Tags: git, github

There is such [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder), albeit an old one, but it didn't seem to help.

I have [a repository](https://github.com/giorgi-m/online-shop). In the repository, I have a GIF file which is roughly 6 MB. It happened so that I pushed different versions of this GIF and apparently all of them were stored in the *.git* folder, which made the size of the Git folder around 40 MB.

From the project folder, I tried running as suggested in the linked question:

```
   git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

But it didn't affect the size of the *.git* folder (do I have to push to see the size reduced?).
Is there something I can do to reduce the *.git* folder size?

Also trying `git gc` didn't seem to reduce the *.git* folder size.

Comment: Related: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Comment: @k0pernikus does it contain an answer? I will go through that ....

Comment: GIF image files are already compressed, and Git's internal compression tricks that normally keep a repository from growing rapidly with each new version of a file simply don't work on already-compressed files. So if the image is 6 MB and you've put in 5 variants of it, you should *expect* this to use about 6*5 = 30 MB right there.

Comment: The part starting with: `Removing Objects` should get your started in the article https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery That beig said, I consider 40MB to be tiny and you have to be aware since git stores the entire history, you will rewrite your repository's history in the process.

Comment: Different use-case, same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/872565/457268

Comment: Somebody also created a script for that: [git forget blob](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/18/completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-with-git-forget-blob/)

Comment: @k0pernikus I will look into your links just for the record I don't want to remove the current GIF file, just the old versions of it.

Comment: `git rm --cached <file name>` and `git add <file name>`

Comment: @Peter you sure that would work? Seems to simplistic compared to all the answers I got above.

Comment: @giorgim it is more like an idea, it removes the file from git and add it back. I am not 100% sure about the .git folder.

Comment: related: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html `Delete files by name` part

Comment: @k0pernikus will there be an easier solution if I don't care about history? e.g. maybe remove .git folder altogether?

Comment: @giorgim The `.git` folder *is* your local git-repository. You should not delete that.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A hacky solution:

```bash
git push # ensure that you push all your last commits from all branches, and
         # take care about your stashes as well because we are going to delete
         # everything.
cd ..
rm -rf online-shop
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:giorgi-m/online-shop.git
```

This last line will clone the repository with only a one commit history.

Hence your `.git` folder will be much lighter. However, you will not have the whole history on your computer and this may not be what you are looking for.

For other users that would like to clone your application, you can tell them in the `README` file that they can fasten download by using the next command:

```bash
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:giorgi-m/online-shop.git
```

---

Another solution, which is [**rewriting history**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), would be to remove all your remote history. You can see more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/6320039):

> Deleting the .git folder may cause problems in your git repository. If you want to delete all your commit history but keep the code in its current state, it is very safe to do it as in the following:
>
> Checkout
>
> ```bash
> git checkout --orphan latest_branch
> ```
>
> Add all the files
>
> ```bash
> git add -A
> ```
>
> Commit the changes
>
> ```bash
> git commit -am "commit message"
> ```
>
> Delete the branch
>
> ```bash
> git branch -D master
> ```
>
> Rename the current branch to master
>
> ```bash
> git branch -m master
> ```
>
> Finally, force update your repository
>
> ```bash
> git push -f origin master
> ```
>
> PS: this will not keep your old commit history around

Comment: history isn't important. After the clone, should I call push again, so that changes are reflected online?

Comment: Also, does it suffer from this problem: "Keep in mind that once you've pushed this code to a remote repository like GitHub and others have cloned that remote repository, you're now in a situation where you're rewriting history. When others try pull down your latest changes after this, they'll get a message indicating that the the changes can't be applied because it's not a fast-forward.". From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history

Comment: I'm not sure I get this question well. My answer is no, since you already pushed everything **before** deleting. (that is **really important to do**, since you `rm -rf`).

Comment: It doesn't: you're not rewritting history, you're just getting a compacted history locally. The remote doesn't change. A quick hint about it: if you don't see `--force` or `--force-with-lease` in a `git push` commit, then it cannot rewrite history.

Comment: And if you want to delete your history on github as well, you could follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/6320039. However, you will **definitely loose your whole history**

Comment: Yes but my goal was to reduce the size of .git folder as it is online because it takes long for users to download.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184688/discussion-between-ulysse-bn-and-giorgim).

Comment: @gmoniava there is yet another solution, you could use [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for your gif image. It helps storing binary data more efficiently, keeping only a hash in the git repo. If this gets 5 or more upvotes I'll consider adding details to this idea :)