# Is it possible to remove all commits from a github repository?

Tags: github

I would like to reset a repository to its virgin state, so that it is the same as if I had used the "create new repo" button on Github, containing no commits. I don't have permissions to delete the repo and recreate it, is there any other way to make a remote repo contain no commits after it has been pushed once? If I try to push an empty, commit-free repo, I get `error: src refspec master does not match any.`.

Comment: no you can not, that's the whole purpose of version control so people don't play evil when they are leaving their company. ;)

Comment: Maybe you could try pushing a commit that removes all of the files, and then rebasing all the history to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/2704032 this answer would help

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remove all the commits associated with a repo, but not all of the issues and pull requests. If you need a completely clean repo, you'll have to delete it and restart.

If you just need to remove the commits, you can do so by removing all of the references, by running a command similar to this:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/* refs/tags/* | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -L1 git push -d origin
```

This will attempt to delete every reference on the server which you have on your system. It will fail for the reference using the default branch, which is usually `master`.

Then, delete the default branch (in this case, `master`) using the API (note that you will need to use a personal access token in place of the text `TOKEN`):

```
curl -v -u token:TOKEN https://api.github.com/repos/bk2204/test-repo/git/refs/heads/master
```

You should substitute your own repo instead of `bk2204/test-repo`. This will delete the last remaining reference, which will leave you without any branches or tags.

Note that the repository will still have references to pull requests, such as `refs/pull/1/head`, which you cannot delete. If you really need all of those gone, then you'll have to start fresh.