# Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository that was created with GitHub Desktop

Tags: github

I created my first GitHub repository using GitHub Desktop (Windows).  It is a real mess with many revisions that are quite meaningless and some versions of files that I would rather were never uploaded.  This was the result of a lot of experimenting to get the feel for how things would appear on GitHub. I want to get rid of all the history versions.

I am tempted to just copy my files on my drive to another folder then delete the repository folder from my drive.  Also delete it from GitHub.

Then create a new repository with GitHub Desktop, perhaps with the same name or with a different name then rename it to the original. Could it be a simple as that or will GitHub still retain the files somewhere?

I haven't tried this because in my searching I keep finding all the complex steps to be performed to remove histories or remove files.

I sort of feel that what I am proposing is too simple.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 1):

All of this got too confusing.
I just did what I said in the start of the thread.
It seems GitHub Desktop has some Username/Password problem and won't let me "Publish branch".

So I went to GitHub and created a new repository and uploaded all the files from my local folder.

It looks good to me.

There may be problems in the future.  I guess I'll cross that bridge when (if) I come to it.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach is to switch to command line and:

- delete the .git folder in your repository
- recreate it (`git init .`)
- reset the origin remote: git remote add origin https://github.com//
- Make a first commit with your current content:

  ```
  git add .
  git commit -m "first commit"
  ```
- overwrite everything on the remote repo

  ```
  git push --force -u origin master
  ```

The end result will be the same repo but with only one commit.

You can then switch back to GitHub Desktop.

Comment: VonC,I have seen instructions like those or even identical.  I didn't understand them.   I don't see a .git folder in my repository (there is one in github Desktop).  As for the command line,Is that from my Windows computer or do I have to use a Linux computer?   Sorry to be so lost.

Comment: @PeteC I meant in your repo on your local disk. (not on GitHub)

Comment: @PeteC For the command line, you can launch it from your GitHub Desktop (CMD or git bash): https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/809#issuecomment-275051069

Comment: I got to the step "Make the first commit...." but it tells me "-m" is unknown switch.  I tried some searches and everybody seems to have a different way of making a first commit.  None similar to your method.  What was the "m"switch supposed to do?

Comment: @PeteC simply type the two commands separately. On the -m: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--mltmsggt

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/583037).

First make sure you have [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) installed, you are going to need to do git commands manually sooner or later.

Go to your local repository on your computer where your project is located. It's a good idea to [show hidden files](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/) so you can see that you have  the [.git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout)-folder and that the [.gitignore](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore)-file is in place.

Go to the folder where the `.git`-folder is, right-click and click  `git bash here`.

Now enter these commands:

**Create Orphan Branch** – Create a new orphan branch in git repository. The newly created branch will not show in ‘git branch’ command.

`git checkout --orphan temp_branch`

**Add Files to Branch** – Now add all files to newly created branch and commit them using following commands. Don't forget `.gitignore`!

```
git add .
git commit -m "the first commit"
```

**Delete master Branch** – Now you can delete the master branch from your git repository.

`git branch -D master`

**Rename Current Branch** – After deleting the master branch, let’s rename newly created branch name to master.

`git branch -m master`

**Push Changes** – You have completed the changes to your local git repository. Finally, push your changes to the remote (Github) repository forcefully.

`git push -f origin master`

**Git overview**
[image: Git overview]