# clear old commits from git and make space in .git

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-gc

I'm trying to clear space in .git folder. I was version controlling the images on my site and maxed out my bitbucket space as my .git folder was growing to over 1gb. My solution was to move my images out of my local directory and into an s3 bucket.

I don't really care about the old commits so I was hoping to delete them and start fresh.

I followed this approach:
[how to delete all commit history in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716658/how-to-delete-all-commit-history-in-github)

As per the steps in the link:

Checkout
`git checkout --orphan latest_branch`

Add all the files
`git add -A`

Commit the changes
`git commit -am "commit message"`

Delete the branch
`git branch -D main`

Rename the current branch to main
`git branch -m main`

Force update your repository
`git push -f origin main`

Then Finally
`git gc -- aggressive -- prune=all`

This worked to clear commits from my bitbucket account but the .git folder hasn't changed size it is still 1gb. I thought git gc would clear the old files but it doesn't seem to work.

At this point how can I clear old files from my git folder?

Comment: Instead of a link, tell us exactly everything you did. What precisely did you say to Git? And what does this have to do with Bitbucket or AWS?

Comment: @matt I have edited my post, I hope this makes more sense now, bitbucket is simply the repository I am using, and it has nothing to do with aws so that was my mistake.

Comment: if no need for old commits, why not just delete .git folder, use git init to create a new one, commit the files you have, and force push? This is also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716732/365237) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683337/365237)

Comment: @eis I am not a very experienced git user so I was worried about messing things up by permanently deleting the folder, but maybe this is actually the most straightforward approach. If I deleted the .git folder, will my project still be associated with my repository? So when doing git init and push it will send new commits to the right repository in my bitbucket account?

Comment: @fred no, it will not be. everything related to git metadata will get deleted. only your actual files will remain. so you will need to establish the association again by adding the origin url. the answers I linked to include instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that the real questions here are:

1. Why didn't the thing I did reduce the size of the *.git* folder significantly?
2. What should I have done?

To discover the answer, let's talk about how commits die. To understand that, you need to know how commits *can't* die. Here's what you need to know:

- A branch is merely a name for one commit. So is a tag name.
- Every commit has at least one "parent" — except for the very first commit you ever made (the "root" commit) and any "orphan" commits that you may create.
- If a commit has a name — that is, a branch name or tag name points to it — *it cannot die.*
- If commit is the parent of a commit that is alive, *it cannot die.*

Now then. If that's how a commit can't die, how *can* a commit die? Well, for a commit to die, it would have to be the case that *no branch or tag name* points to a commit that calls *this* commit its parent at any depth. In other words, imagine a chain of commit parentage; well, a commit can only die if *no* chain of commit parentage starting with a branch or tag name reaches it.

Okay, so now let's talk about what *you* did. You deleted `main`, in the hopes that this would cause all existing commits to die. But it seems like they didn't. So let me ask you this: was `main` the *only branch* you had? Because if it wasn't, then all those other branch names still exist, and they are keeping all their parents alive *all the way back to the root commit.*

Moreover, you've got a remote. So you also have *remote-tracking branches* that mirror the state of that remote. So in addition to *your* `main`, you've also got an `origin/main`. What you did had *no effect* on that. So that `origin/main` is keeping all your commits alive, *all the way back to the root commit*.

So what you did probably didn't cause *any* commits to die!

And that would explain why your *.git* folder didn't get significantly smaller after what you did.

So, to do it correctly the way *you* did it, you would need to say `git branch` to find out what branches you have, and delete each of those branches. Plus, you'd need to say `git tag --list` to find out what tags you have, and delete each of those tags.

But even that wouldn't be enough, because what about all the remote-tracking branches you have? To see those, you'd say `git branch --remote`. You'd need to delete all those remote branches too! But you can't just delete them; you have to *push* the deletion. For every remote-tracking branch, you'd need to say `git push --delete origin <branchname>`.

Sounds like a lot of work, doesn't it?

And that's why the simplest way to do what you want to do is just to checkout the state of things that you like, which is presumably `main`, and then just *throw the entire *.git* folder away.* Then say `git init` and start all over with a fresh commit. Also throw your remote away and make a fresh remote. Hook the two together with `git remote add`, and push your brand new clean repository to the branch new clean remote.

Comment: And if any of what I just said comes as a surprise to you, you should read my introduction to Git: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/. It tells you what Git is, and once you know that, everything I just said is completely obvious.

Comment: thanks for the article link, very thorough and helpful. I ended up deleting the git folder which was the obvious approach from the beginning. I've done this in the past but always assumed that I was resorting to this measure because I wasn't savvy enough to do it through git commands. In the end though if you understand git as you explain it, it did make more sense to dump the git folder.

Comment: Yup, thanks; you've had some useful comments, I just wanted to make sure you understood what was happening.