Git ignore says files exists and dont exists at same time
As the title suggest i am having a dumb git error. My .gitignore contains
build.zip
build/
*.mov
*.mp4
*.webm
*.zip
.VSCodeCounter
node_modules/
node_modules/*
node_modules

And when i git add . then commit then push i get the following error, Please notice in the highlights that when i try to remove the files from the commit it says that they don't exist. I have completely removed the cache with gitrm -r --cached . as well


Is your gitignore file named .gitignore (take note of the .), and located at the root of the directory?

yes it is. i added in the .mov line and it "removed" all the videos. which it obviously did not remove anything because its still showing up as an error

You have removed the files from your current commit, but that does not remove them from the git repository.  They are still there in the old commits.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-can-i-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-the-commit-history-in-the-git-reposito.

its the first commit

Presumably those files used to be tracked and are part of a commit somewhere in main's history. Even though they don't exist in the current working tree, they're still part of the repo. You'll likely need to re-write the branch history to remove all references to them. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/11082165

Using git rm doesn't remove the files from what is already committed.  Removing the files from the current directory doesn't remove them from what is already committed.  Playing around with .gitignore may be causing some confusion in the warning messages, but that also does not remove the already commited files from the repository.  To eliminate the file size limit errors you need to remove the files from the repository completely.  See the link I referenced on how to do this.

Thanks man, I'm running the command mentioned in the link you posted now. Seems like overkill to do such a simple task, idk.

The problem is that git tries very hard to keep you from losing old versions of your files.  So, it doesn't make it easy to do exactly that.  The only reason that this arises is that local git doesn't care about your file sizes, but github does.

since this was the first commit, i just deleted the entire commit history https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716658/how-to-delete-all-commit-history-in-github
Its now working again
