# How to remove first n commit messages in git?

Tags: git

I was configuring git and during this phase created a few test commits (I was commiting a change of 1 character with pointless commit message). After these I was using git and created a lot of normal commits. So right now when I review commit history with `git rev-list --all --pretty` and scroll far enough I see these terrible first N commits.

I was trying to get rid of them and I found suggestions to redo git (which is not a valid idea  for me). I also found that the [first commit is special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10911506/1090562) so I can not remove it.

But is there a way to remove first N commits (excluding the very first one) and rename the first one?

Answer (score 4):

If you have not "published" your commits (made them available to others), you can use the history rewriting effect of `git rebase` to discard the early commits.

This rewriting works by *copying* all the commits you want to retain, to new commits.  The old ones are then abandoned.  If you *have* published the commits, any other people who grabbed them already have them and you cannot do anything about that; and making these new copies of the ones you want to keep, and asking them to switch over to the new copies, makes a lot of useless work for them.  So it's not polite and you should not do it without a really good reason.

If it's a private repository, though, you're all good.

To be able to rewrite every commit starting from the beginning, use `git rebase -i --root`.  This will give you a list of every commit, including the first one, with `pick` commands for each; simply delete the ones you want to drop.  (Note that this will "flatten out" any merges.  It's possible to preserve them, even while removing some commits, but I have not experimented with this; see the `BUGS` section of the [`git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html).)